# How to show that $2\times 10^{18}<20!<3 \times 10^{18}$ without calculator?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I want to find the first digit of $20!$

By calculator $20! = 2.43290200817664 \times 10^{18}$.

So I want to show that $2\times 10^{18}<20!<3 \times 10^{18}$

Thank you.

Comment: You definitely need to provide more context for this question.

Comment: $20$ is small enough so that one could just play around with, multiplying factors to get them close to a power of $10$ and see what you get. This gives me $20! = 2.86\cdot 10^{18}\cdot (0.95) (0.9996) (0.972) (0.96)^2$ which is enough to give the result.

Answer (score 10):

Simply divvy up the product nicely. I'll demonstrate how it can be done for the lower bound.
$$\begin{align}20!&=(20\cdot15)\cdot(19\cdot 16)\cdot(18\cdot17)\cdot(14\cdot 13\cdot11)\cdot(12\cdot9)\cdot10\cdot 8!
\\&=300\cdot304\cdot306\cdot2002\cdot108\cdot10\cdot40320
\\&>3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1\cdot4\cdot 10^{2+2+2+3+2+1+4}
\\&=6^3\cdot 10^{16}
\\&=2.16\times 10^{18}
\end{align}$$

The idea is to get near to a power of $10$. If you are trying to find a lower bound, you want multiples just above a power of $10$ while the upper bound can be generated with multiples just below a power of $10$ (see Barry Cipra's answer).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a counterpart to Peter Woolfitt's answer.

$$\begin{align}
20!&=(20\cdot15\cdot10\cdot5\cdot2)(19\cdot7\cdot3)(11\cdot9)(8\cdot6\cdot4)(16\cdot14)(17\cdot13)(18\cdot12)\\
&=(3\cdot10^4)((20-1)(20+1))(99)(192)((15+1)(15-1))((15+2)(15-2))(15+3)(15-3))\\
&\lt(3\cdot10^4)(400)(100)(200)(15^2)(15^2)(15^2)\\
&=(3\cdot10^4)(10000)(100)(1000)(3^6\cdot5^3)\\
&=(3\cdot10^{13})(729\cdot5^3)\\
&\lt(3\cdot10^{13})(800\cdot5^3)\\
&=(3\cdot10^{13})(2^5\cdot5^5)\\
&=3\cdot10^{18}
\end{align}$$

**Added later**:  A somewhat slicker alternative:

$$\begin{align}
20!&=(20\cdot15\cdot10)(19\cdot5)(18\cdot16\cdot3)((17\cdot6)(14\cdot7))((13\cdot8)(12\cdot4\cdot2))(11\cdot9)\\
&=(3000)(95)(9\cdot96)((100+2)(100-2))((100+4)(100-4))(99)\\
&\lt(3\cdot10^3)(10^2)(10\cdot10^2)(10^4)(10^4)(10^2)\\
&=3\cdot10^{18}
\end{align}$$

Remark:  Possibly the most challenging thing to check here is that every number from $2$ to $20$ appears (at least once) on the right hand side of the first line.  After that, the most difficult computation (for me) was calculating $17\cdot6=102$.

Comment: Neatly done! ${}$

Answer (score 4):

We have [these estimates for the central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) for $n\ge1$:
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{4n}} \leq {2n \choose n} \leq \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
and so
$$
(n!)^2\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{4n}} \leq(2n)! \le (n!)^2 \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}
$$
Apply this to $n=10$, using that $10!=3628800$, and get
$$
2.19 \times 10^{18} \le 20! \le 2.48 \times 10^{18}
$$

I did use a calculator for these bounds but it's probably feasible to do it by hand.

Here is a calculation for the upper bound that is feasible by hand:

$
\qquad
10! = 3628800 < 3.7 \times 10^6 \implies (10!)^2 < 3.7^2 \times 10^{12} < 1.37 \times 10^{13}$

$
\qquad
4^{10} = 2^{20} = 1048576 < 1.05 \times 10^6$

$
\qquad
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{31}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{25}} = 0.2$

and so

$
\qquad
(10!)^2 \dfrac{4^{10}}{\sqrt{31}} <  1.37 \cdot 1.05 \cdot 0.2 \times 10^{19} = 0.2877 \times 10^{19} < 2.9 \times 10^{18}
$

For the lower bound, we can do

$
\qquad
10! = 3628800 > 3.6 \times 10^6 \implies (10!)^2 > 3.6^2 \times 10^{12} = 1.296  \times 10^{13}$

$
\qquad
4^{10} = 2^{20} = 1048576 > 1.04 \times 10^6$

$
\qquad
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{40}} > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{49}} = \dfrac17$

and so

$
\qquad
(10!)^2 \dfrac{4^{10}}{\sqrt{40}} >  \dfrac{1.296 \cdot 1.04}{7} \times 10^{19}  > 1.92 \times 10^{18}
$

unfortunately not quite what we need.

A better estimate $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{40}} > 0.15$ will give

$
\qquad
(10!)^2 \dfrac{4^{10}}{\sqrt{40}} >  1.296 \cdot 1.04 \cdot 0.15 \times 10^{19}  > 2.02 \times 10^{18}
$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling formula is

$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$

So
$20! \approx \sqrt{40\pi}(\frac{20}{e})^{20} \approx 2.4 * 10^{18}$

Comment: Ah right - not such a good answer :-) but let me think about calculation on paper or in the mind